# TextWrapping textbox in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've been trying to make my textboxes in my DataGrid wrap. I got it working but it seems to break the Text binding.

XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <!-- <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Value}">
                        </TextBox>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle> -->
</DataGrid>
```

I add the columns and rows using a data set like so.

CS

```
    #region Variables
    private DataTable m_stringData = new DataTable();
    private DataSet m_stringDataSet = new DataSet();
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public LocEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AddColumn("ID", 100);
        AddString("Test");
        dataGrid.DataContext = m_stringData;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methods

    private void AddColumn(string l_columnName, int l_iWidth)
    {
        m_stringData.Columns.Add(l_columnName, typeof(string));

        dataGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = l_columnName,
            Width = l_iWidth,
            Binding = new Binding(l_columnName)
            //Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", l_columnName))
        });
    }

    private void AddString(string l_stringID)
    {
        m_stringData.Rows.Add();
        m_stringData.Rows[m_stringData.Rows.Count - 1][0] = l_stringID;
    }

    #endregion
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. By setting the Element and EditingElementStyle, I don't have to reset the Binding.

```
DataGridTextColumn l_column = new DataGridTextColumn();
l_column.Header = l_columnName;
l_column.Binding = new Binding(l_columnName);
l_column.Width = l_iWidth;

Style l_textStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBlock));
l_textStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBlock.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap));
l_column.ElementStyle = l_textStyle;
Style l_textEditStyle = new Style(typeof(TextBox));
l_textEditStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(TextBox.TextWrappingProperty, TextWrapping.Wrap));
l_column.EditingElementStyle = l_textEditStyle;

dataGrid.Columns.Add(l_column);
```

Answer (score 1):

This inserts the GridViewColumn directly into the GridView, but it worked for me.

```
<ListView Name="myListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="HEADER NAME" x:Name="header">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In order to see the wrapped text fully, you will need to set the height of the rows to be large enough to see this (or do height conversions dynamically).

```
<My:ToHeightConverter x:Key="heightConverter" />

<Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ElementName=myListView, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource heightConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

And then in the code behind the GridView:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class ToHeightConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        return (((double)value * 10);      //return the height wanted here
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know how many columns I will end up with. So my DataTable has to do this work for me. I can't statically create my columns in XAML. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just add TextWrapping to all TextBoxes in your DataGrid, I would suggest making an implicit style for them in your `DataGrid.Resources`

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

The reason why the data isn't showing up in your Template is because you're missing the `ContentPresenter`. This is the object that displays the rendered content of the actual `DataGridCell`. The `DataGridCell` itself has no idea what the content of its cell is, so doesn't know what the binding is.

For example, this works

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                </TextBlock>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But not this

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

because the `Content` is whatever object happens to be in the cell at the time, whether it is a `TextBox`, `TextBlock`, `ComboBox`, etc

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I just add the Resources part, my textboxes dont seem to get affected. At least I don't notice any changes. I'm getting an "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource." with the Style. What am I missing? Again, thanks so much.

Comment: Ok I was missing some XAML tags. Still no text wrapping though. And The text disapears when I select the cell.